# How to create a script to check for internet connection?

Tags: wireless, internet, scripts, cron

I'm new to programming in linux. I started bitcoin mining using linux mint xfce 15. I'm really good following directions, just don't know how to start.  I need to create a script that can run every 15 minutes to check if there is a connection to the interet if there is no connection, restart wifi connection.  My asus eee b202 is losing internet conection some how, eventhough wifi is connected. So to fix it I disconnect from wifi and reconnect again. With the script added as to a cron job, I can avoid doing that.  Thanks before hand.

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot the wireless?

Answer (score 2):

Add a cron job for root to run the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
    service network-manager restart
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```bsh
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

To add a cron job for root, use the following command:

```bsh
sudo crontab -e
```

And your cron entry from the crontab file should look like:

```bsh
0/15 * * * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: I have to use `if ! ping -c 1 google.com; then`, and a crontab entry with `*/15` not `0/15` to make this work.